# Why won't my NET SDK properly install and work on vs code?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to learn C# in visual studio with a tutorial online, but to do that it says I need the .NET SDK thing. I've downloaded it more times than I can count, yet it still work work on VSCODE or in my terminal.
[This is the installer for both vscode and .net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCcln.png)

This is what happens when I try to check if it works in my terminal
[I typed dotnet and then dotnet --info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8idk1.png)

It just says I don't have the SDK installed. I've tried to re-install at the link in the terminal and the ones online, but it just wont work.

If anyone has a clue of to what is going on, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I should have installed the x86 version...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing probably env variable or missing adding to path. You suppose to find place where it was installed and try to run dotnet from place where it was installed.